# download a file properly with python if no Content-Length is provided

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download

how can i properly download a file with python if the http response does not contain a Content-Length header?

im having this issue with appengine's send_blob() function which for some reason does not add the Content-Length header on bigger (20mb+) blobs.

right now im using urllib.urlretrieve() but sometimes it does not download the whole file. 
what im doing right now is sending the content length before downloading the file so i can check if the file has the right size before proceeding.

im not sure if there is a better way to do this.

the headers of one of those files:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2011 19:41:34 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Connection: close
```

i just tried to use wget to download a file with `wget --server-response --continue` and the headers are:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
  Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2011 14:08:13 GMT
  Server: Google Frontend
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Length: unspecified [application/octet-stream]
```

Comment: does closing the HTTP connection (from the server side) work? (not sure if that produces well-defined behavior, but it's my best guess)

Comment: When it doesn't send the `Content-Length`, is it using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`?

Comment: @ninjagecko: don't actually know if its possible to close the connection manually when using the send_blob() function.

Comment: @SteveJessop: i edited the question by adding the headers sent with one of those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine is sending the response using [chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), which allows the client to determine when the response has completed. urllib should be dealing with this for you, though; it seems likely that your connection is getting terminated prematurely for some reason, and urllib isn't communicating that to you (or you're catching and ignoring the exception).

Answer (score 1):

If the server gives no indication of the length of the requested data, sends you some data and then closes the connection, then the *HTTP client* must assume that all of it has been successfully transferred.

Only using additional, non-HTTP information, such as a checksum or other error correction within the payload format, can the *application* determine that an error has occurred, and use the [HTTP Range header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.1) (i.e. `Range: bytes=NNNN-`) in a subsequent client request to resume the transfer.

If the server does not support the `Range` header, which you may conclude if the server transmits response header `Accept-Ranges: none` at any time, then as far as I know you have no recourse against the broken server implementation, except to periodically retry the request hoping it eventually serves a response that passes error detection.

Footnote: It is not a surprise to me that the `Content-Length` header is missing when serving blob contents.  Many database APIs do not allow the length of a blob to be tested without actually retrieving the entire thing.  I suspect the reason for this is lack of support for this test in SQL engines themselves.

Comment: This is only the case if not using chunked encoding.